# Powershell script how to access variable

Tags: powershell

I have a master script `master.ps1` which executes two child ps1 scripts like below:

```
& "child1.ps1"

& "child2.ps1"
```

The problem I have now is at the end of `master.ps1` script, based on certain variable values set in `child1.ps1` and `child2.ps1`, I need to determine if I need to send an email or not.

Is there anyway this can be acheived? I'm using powershell 2.0

Thanks,

Comment: You need to set some variable with *parent scope* from within the children, see [**About Scopes**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Comment: I'm actually quite new to powershell script. Can you provide a code example? For example, how should I set the variable say $a = "sth" in the child1.ps1 so that from within master.ps1 I can read its value?

Comment: I have no idea what your children scripts do, but you need some variable in `master.ps1` that you set from the children. Say in `master.ps1` you create a variable `$sendemail`, then in the children if you need to indicate that variable should be set to, e.g. true, you would use `$global:sendemail = "true"` to explicitly specify the `global` scope for `$sendemail` in the `master.ps1` is being set.

Comment: My understanding is the global scope will make the variable available to any powershell instances which is not really what I want. I only intend to make it available in the caller and children scripts hierarchy. Or maybe I'm trying to achieve sth via a completely wrong approach?

Comment: "*In Windows PowerShell, all scopes are child scopes of the global scope, but you can create many scopes and many recursive scopes. Unless you explicitly make the items private, the items in the parent scope are available to the child scope. However, items that you create and change in the child scope do not affect the parent scope, unless you explicitly specify the scope when you create the items.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is execute the `child1.ps1` and `child2.ps1` scripts in the scope of the *calling* script.

You can do this easily by dot-sourcing the scripts (`. <command>`), rather than using the call operator (`& <command>`):

```
. child1.ps1
. child2.ps1
# $a is now available
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. I guess this is the kind of answer people are expecting when come here, rather than seeing some copied and pasted long texts.  Is there any other differences between using dot-sourcing and the call operator?

Comment: No, the fundamental difference is the scope in which the command is executed

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the explanation.